# Will producing a Protego Charm reflect more than one simultaneous spell?

Tags: harry-potter

Protego Charm is also known as the Shield Charm and the Reflecting Charm, since it's used to create a temporary shield barrier that will block certain spells, and acts like a mirror that makes the spells backfire to the ones who casted it.

However, what will happen if a wizard casts a Shield Charm for defensive purposes and more than one colliding spell hit him/her? Would the attacks still be reflected to their owners?

Specifically, I am giving an example of Professor Mcgonagall in HP and OTP, 4 stunning spells hit her squarely in the chest. If she produced the Shield Charm, would they have been reflected, or will they still stun her, since they are too strong and beyond measure?

Comment: See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieibsVyVYnU) - in the last 10 seconds of the video Kingsley blocks two spells with one non-verbal shield.

Comment: As some other answers explain well, I think this has to come down to the strength and experience of the wizards involved. Could Dumbledore or McGonagall deflect two or more at once from a lesser wizard? Absolutely. Could Colin Creevey against Bellatrix? Almost certainly not. And Hermione vs Dolohov for example? I think that would be very uncertain and depend on specific details of the confrontation.

Comment: @ThruGog you should have explained it as an answer rather than a comment. It has a good point.

Comment: Oh I just may! Tough to base it on evidence though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to say yes it would based off of a few things.

-We never here of someone casting a curse in quick succession twice, which would be a strategy if shield charms were broken on impact and commonly used.

-When Ron is about to storm out of the tent in the Deathly Hallows book, a fight nearly breaks out and a shield charm is cast that physically prevents Hermione chasing after Ron for a large enough period that covers at least several lines of dialogue. The attitude of Harry and Ron in this section makes it seem they assume there is no more to be done, like staring at each other through unbreakable glass. It seems strange to me they would act this way if the shield could be knocked away so easy, the shield is being used as a metaphor to refer to a fairly serious rift between them.

Answer (score 4):

Several questions on this site with [accepted answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bharry-potter%5D%20intent) examine the experience, skill and particularly **intent** of wizards when casting spells against one another.

As such, while there aren't many concrete, canon examples beyond what @Gallifreian points out in his comment (Kingsley Shacklebolt using a non-verbal sheild charm to deflect/absorb two spells at once), I think a useful answer looks like this:

A very experienced wizard, such as Dumbledore (well-known for his superior power, knowledge and skill than most) should very easily be able to defend himself against a weaker, less experienced attacker - or more than one. Remember for example, his confidence against Ministry Aurors such as Dawlish. Remember also, Voldemort and Bellatrix were able to fend off three attackers each for a period of time during the final stages of the Battle of Hogwarts.

Similarly, a weaker, inexperienced wizard is unlikely to be able to defend himself against one more skilled attacker using a shield charm, let alone two or three. Picture the terror in most Hogwarts students who aim to match their good DADA OWL grades against a notorious Death Eater such as Bellatrix or Dolohov.

As in all interesting examples of combat, when similarly-matched duellers are facing off, the chances of success are far more difficult to call. If, say, Remus Lupin was duelling, say, Lucius Malfoy, I think the success and failure of spells is down to many fine factors as opposed to "Lupin uses Stupefy, which will definitely work, unless Malfoy deflects it at the right time with Protego." These factors are likely to include, but not be limited to:
-Experience
-Skills
-Innate magical power
-Levels of fatigue
-Intent - surely a killing curse from an enraged dark wizard is far more dangerous than one cast by a wizard who would rather not kill but feels they have to (remember Barty Crouch Jnr's comments on the attempts of a classroom of fourth-years who may attempt to using Avada Kedavra on him).
-Timing
-Accuracy of casting - etc!

So, will a Shield Charm defend against more than one curse at a time? It depends on the power, experience and intent of the caster of both the offensive and defensive spell and various other factors during the moment of battle.